# Single Child Scroll View Doesn't work with Gesture Detector

Tags: flutter, dart

I have Created a `SingleChildScrollView`. The Gesture Detector has a parent Container(red) and a Child Container(blue). The scroll view works on the parent but not on the child. What should I do? Thanks for the help.
This is the code.

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.redAccent[200],
                height: 1000.0,
                width: 500.0,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              ),

              GestureDetector(
                onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                  print("Start");
                  print(details.localPosition);
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent[200],
                  height: 10000.0,
                  width: 500.0,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                ),

              )
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onVerticalDragUpdate` is stopping the `SingleChildScrollView` from scrolling because it just detects the Vertical Drag Update, when you drag your widget by holding it, it neglects the ScrollView and listen to the draggable updates of the widget.
Run the below code. It is working for me now.

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.redAccent[200],
                height: 1000.0,
                width: 500.0,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                // onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
                //   print("Start");
                //   print(details.localPosition);
                // },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent[200],
                  height: 1000.0,
                  width: 500.0,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                ),

              )
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Comment: I wanted to scroll on both Containers and also know the ```details.localPosition```. the above code won't give the position.

Comment: Well Lakshan, according to me, i think it is not possible.

Comment: How can it know it should get the touch detected or it should scroll?

Comment: ohh, Can't it do both?

Comment: According to my knowledge. No! But there is always a hack

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the GestureDetector with SingleChildScrollView like this.

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        color: Colors.redAccent[200],
        height: 1000.0,
        width: 500.0,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
      ),
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onVerticalDragUpdate: (DragUpdateDetails details) {
            print("Start");
            print(details.localPosition);
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blueAccent[200],
            height: 10000.0,
            width: 500.0,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Still Doesn't scroll on the blue container. only on the red Container.

Comment: Hey Lakshan! Can you tell me what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You want Scroll on both the Containers? If yes then check the answer

Comment: @LakshanCosta did you ever solve this issue?? if yes kindly pass me the hack.

Comment: I'm sorry dude. I think I did but I don't have the code with me(my files got deleted :(    ), and can't remember